# MacBook Air stuck during update to 13.2.1

Tags: software-update, ventura, macos

I’m updating my MacBook Air from 13.2.0 to 13.2.1 but it’s stuck in the screen you usually get after reboot.
It says :
[image]
“The update process might require several minutes and the monitor will shut down for a maximum duration of one minute “

Except it’s in this state since three hours now.

What should I do? Is it safe to force shutdown or do I risk bricking it?

Comment: Is 13.13.0 correct?

Comment: 13.2.0 to 13.2.1, will correct the post

Comment: You really don’t have a choice here.  Hold the power button and turn it off.  Then wait a few seconds (count down from 10 if you like), and turn it back on.  It should pick up where it left off.

Comment: Indeed, I powered it off and it restarted to 13.2.0 like anything happened. I suspect it was trying to run a time machine backup. Afterwards the update took 30 min.